# CS50 - pset4 filter's blur function is just counting upwards

Tags: c, filter, blur, cs50

I'm working on filter (less) in pset4, and I've got every other function fully checked out, but when I run check50 on this, I get the following responses for blur:

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "120 140 150\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
    expected "80 95 105\n", not "40 50 60\n"
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
    expected "70 85 95\n", not "10 20 30\n"
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "10 20 30\n40 5..."
```

That first one makes it look like I'm doing some sort of rounding error (although a very inconsistent one, rounding that first digit down and then the last digit up), but then the errors get stranger and stranger to me as the images get larger, until by the last array I'm generating:

```
10 20 30
40 50 60
70 80 90
100 110 120
110 130 140
120 140 150
130 150 160
140 160 170
195 204 213
205 214 223
225 234 243
245 254 253
50 28 90
0 0 0
255 255 255
85 85 85
```

I'm not sure how I started doing that, but I don't like it at all. Could anyone give me advice as to what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks very much for your time. The code is below:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    // copy the image
    // figure out blur data from the original picture and apply to the copy
    RGBTRIPLE tempArray[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            int validPixels = 0;
            // cycle through area around a pixel
            for (int blurRadiusX = -1; blurRadiusX > 1; blurRadiusX++)
            {
                for (int blurRadiusY = -1; blurRadiusY > 1; blurRadiusY++)
                {
                // check area around pixels to see if it's at a valid location
                    if ((i + blurRadiusX > 0) && (i + blurRadiusX < (height - 1)) && (j + blurRadiusY > 0) && (j + blurRadiusY < (width - 1)))
                    {
                        // an array adding all the values up, to be averaged out later
                        tempArray[i][j].rgbtRed = tempArray[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i + blurRadiusX][j + blurRadiusY].rgbtRed;
                        tempArray[i][j].rgbtGreen = tempArray[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i + blurRadiusX][j + blurRadiusY].rgbtGreen;
                        tempArray[i][j].rgbtBlue = tempArray[i][j].rgbtBlue + image[i + blurRadiusX][j + blurRadiusY].rgbtBlue;
                        validPixels++;
                    }
                }
            // if there are enough bytes to add these correctly, add and then divide by valid pixels
            // this should be applied to the image after tempArray is fully populated
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(tempArray[i][j].rgbtRed / validPixels * 1.00);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(tempArray[i][j].rgbtGreen / validPixels * 1.00);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(tempArray[i][j].rgbtBlue / validPixels * 1.00);
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

And here's CS50's page about the problem set: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/4/filter/less/

Answer (score 1):

So I actually had the same problem, assuming I'm reading this correctly. Essentially the issue is that the RGBTRIPLE struct is not storing three ints, it's storing three bytes, one for each of the three colors. So as you add numbers to get a total that's greater than 255, it 'resets' to 0. Rather than using an RGBTRIPLE as your temp, I would use three integers.

For example:

```c
int red;
int green;
int blue;
```

Then just increment these numbers and operate on them instead. Let me know if that doesn't fix it and I'll take a deeper look, but it looks like that is the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't change the outputs at all. But when I was checking through, I noticed that the blur function just didn't seem to be changing the input picture at all.

Comment: Ah okay. I will tell you though if you are using an RGBTRIPLE as your temp you will see additional problems.

Comment: That's a very good point... I had some issues not remembering that BYTEs weren't just ints in the earlier problems, but I spaced on it when it came to this.  I actually ended up scrapping this version and am trying to rewrite the whole function for greater readability; I appreciate you helping me out with this!